# Gnu Parted Error in HardDisk of Linux?

Tags: linux, partition, parted, gpt

Why the error getting when excuting the fdisk -l command in linux.

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb 

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real limitation is that the `fdisk` tool in the `util-linux` package doesn't support [GPT-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition tables, which you can find on **any** disk.  However, they're commonly found on disks greater than 2 GiB, because the old [MBR-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition tables don't support sizes that large.

The easiest fix is, as the error suggested, to just use the [GNU Parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/) software instead.  If you'd like to still have the old `fdisk` style interface, the `gnu-fdisk` package provides [GNU Fdisk](http://www.gnu.org/software/fdisk/), an alternate version of `fdisk` that **does** support GPT.

Answer (score 1):

I have find it finally, as it  is an simple concept. /dev/sdb has 3000GB where fidsk won't support, because it will support only upto  2000GB harddisk. Instead fdisk we have to use parted.